# Alternative to Elm record extension

Tags: records, elm

I am trying to migrate a library from Elm 0.15 to 0.16. The record extension mechanism has been removed.

[My library](https://github.com/jastice/boxes-and-bubbles) offers physics calculations on bodies (represented as record), and uses record extension to allow users to add labels and other metadata about the bodies.

My [example code](https://github.com/jastice/boxes-and-bubbles/blob/c2e082dc694248b9dc5ff5676d1da160d7c59394/src/Example.elm#L36) shows this use by adding a label to all the bodies after their creation:

```
labeledBodies = map (\b -> { b | label = bodyLabel b.restitution b.inverseMass }) someBodies
```

This list of labeled bodies is also passed to the library:

```
main = Signal.map scene (run labeledBodies tick)
```

What sort of works: hardcoding a `meta` parameter into the `Body` like this:

```
type alias Body a = {
  pos: Vec2, -- reference position (center)
  velocity: Vec2, -- direction and speed
  inverseMass: Float, -- we usually use only inverse mass for calculations
  restitution: Float, -- bounciness factor
  shape: Shape,
  meta: a
}
```

But this makes the API more clumsy because it forces the helper functions to take an extra parameter. Is there a more elegant way to deal with this change?

Comment: Is `label` really necessary on the record to begin with? Could you instead call `bodyLabel` from inside the `run` function?

Comment: In this case, yes (but it would be extra work doing it each time), but in the general case, no: I want to be able to track other metadata as well which is not dependent on the body (eg hitpoints, unique id, whatever)

Answer (score 1):

What if the `meta` field had type `Dict String String`? Then you wouldn't have to do any crazy type variables clumsiness. However, you lose guarantees that all the records you pass in do indeed have labels, so you have to work with a `Maybe String` when you do `Dict.get "label" r.meta`.

Comment: I did consider adding a field for a fixed id or metadata, but that won't work so nicely for the general case, where I don't want to track only String values.

Answer (score 1):

What about using a tagged union type?

```
type BodyWithMeta = 
  LabeledBody Body String

labeledBodies = map (\b -> LabeledBody b (bodyLabel b.restitution b.inverseMass)) someBodies
```

Comment: This is possibly not fully clear from the question. But I want the `run` function to not lose the association between body and attached metadata. With your suggestion, `run` would have to know the `LabeledBody` type, while I was hoping to keep the metadata generic.

Comment: does `run` need the label at all?

Comment: `run` doesn't need it (it knows nothing about it), but it needs to be part of the data structure that `run` works with

Comment: Then couldn't you map over the list of `labeledBodies` and get a list of `Body` to pass in to `run`?

Comment: No, because then I lose the association between body and label (in the general case, the data is not derivable from the body)